# How to adjust the accuracy of the colorbar so that more data can be visualized ？

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

Since the value range of the data to be visualized is very large, and the densely distributed smaller data cannot be displayed, how to adjust the accuracy of the color gamut so that more values can be visualized?

```py
# show output image
plt.style.use(astropy_mpl_style)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
# ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=out_wcs.celestial)
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection=out_wcs.celestial)
im = ax.imshow(out_data, cmap='viridis', vmin=out_min, vmax=out_max)

lon, lat = ax.coords
lon.set_major_formatter('dd:mm')
lat.set_major_formatter('dd:mm')
lon.set_axislabel('R.A. [deg]')
lat.set_axislabel('Dec [deg]')

ax = plt.gca()
# ax.invert_xaxis()
cbarr = plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: the colorbar range is defined by `vmin=out_min, vmax=out_max`, so adjust `out_min` and `out_max` to better fit the `out_data` values

Comment: thank you, well, due to the existence of the great value, most of the smaller data can not be well represented, for example, the data range is [-0.0001~25], how to adjust vmin and vmax in this case?

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: You could use a log normalized colormap by using `LogNorm`. See details [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LogNorm.html)

Comment: Use LogNorm, the matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=None, vmax=None, clip=False), vmin should > 0, however, the data range is  [-0.0001~25], how to solve it ?  or have another method ? thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [`SymLogNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm.html). Having said that - I don't see any data points >10 in your output. Is vmax=25 really necessary?